# Nameserver Problem

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I installed Virtualmin GPL with BIND, etc. I created a virtual host for my main domain, and edited the zone file, added the A records for the nameservers `ns1.mydomain.com` and `ns2.mydomain.com`. All looks good from the VPS, whenever I do a `dig` or `nslookup`, all seems fine, returning correct details.

But when I test externally, there are no results. I tried several sites such as `intodns`, etc. It says my nameservers doesn't point to any IP. I have registered my nameservers with the appropriate IP in my registrar, and I even contacted support to verify this, and they told me that the registration was successful, but when they `dig` my nameservers, there's no ip address.

I can also connect to my server IP's port 53. Also, I know that the DNS propagation is 24-48 hours. But there has to be some server that can return the correct results by now.

Please lead me to the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look the zone files? Do you have the `ns` records? They usually go after the `SOA` and before the `MX`.

Take a look at the sample zone file bellow and compare with yours to see if something is missing:

```
$TTL    86400 ; 24 hours could have been written as 24h or 1d
$ORIGIN example.com.
@  1D  IN    SOA ns1.example.com.   hostmaster.example.com. (
                  2002022401 ; serial
                  3H ; refresh
                  15 ; retry
                  1w ; expire
                  3h ; minimum
                 )
       IN  NS     ns1.example.com. ; in the domain
       IN  NS     ns2.smokeyjoe.com. ; external to domain
       IN  MX  10 mail.another.com. ; external mail provider
; server host definitions
ns1    IN  A      192.168.0.1  ;name server definition     
www    IN  A      192.168.0.2  ;web server definition
ftp    IN  CNAME  www.example.com.  ;ftp server definition
; non server domain hosts
bill   IN  A      192.168.0.3
fred   IN  A      192.168.0.4
```

Comment: Oh, for some reason, virtualmin placed the NS records at the middle of A records. I placed it after SOA, and before any other records. Thanks.

Comment: @ruel I am not sure if the order matters, but tell me later if it works.

Comment: Nope, didn't work :<

Comment: @ruel post the results of `dig <domain>` and `dig @<dns server> domain`, use another dns server for this last test, like your ISP or something.